# Is it important to keep private members hidden at runtime?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

Typescript's "**private**" members are not private at runtime.  Conversely, an old fashion closure keeps private members private at runtime.

Is there merit in keeping private members private at runtime?

Comment: What's the merit of keeping things private in the first place? Whom are you trying to deny access?

Comment: @Bergi That’s why I was asking.  My understanding is that it is to prevent dependency on variables that may change or that require additional logic to be set or to get.  Which makes me think it might be important to keep them hidden at runtime.  If someone were to come in and try to write a script outside of the Typescript source that relied on objects they observed at runtime they might create dependences on variables directly and create bugs or idiomatic snafus...

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you would simply blame it on those who were not using TypeScript :-) The merit in not using closures is that they're more costly at runtime. And in general, you cannot keep things completely private if someone is running JS code on the same page, so there's no security issue.

Comment: @Bergi Don’t most modern JavaScript engines optimize out theoretical closure performance costs?  That said,  I see the point , it reminds me of “security through obscurity” idiom.  That said — short of modifying the source code — closures are pretty bullet proof at keeping data private.  Performance aside is there really no value in runtime private members?

Comment: Notice: JavaScript (and also TypeScript) will have [private fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) and [private methods](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-methods) soon.

Comment: Also I don't think it's even possible to have "real" private fields for class in JavaScript (ES5). I mean, when you create new instance of a given class, and different instances have different private fields (not pointing to the same variable as in naive implementation with closures). I'm not sure you can express this in ES5 JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *private* modifier is just a way to make other developers aware that the function should not be called from everywhere as it does some dangerous modifications. Or it is just private to keep the public methods clean. Whatsoever it is only relevant for developers and not for the engine.

Answer (score 0):

private/public is only meaningful for compiler.

There is no concept of OOP in machine language, not to mention accessibility.

That's the same in your case. Typescript is compiled into javascript and hence the developer do not need to care about what it is after compilation in most of the case. They should be handled by ts compiler instead. The compile time warning and error should be adequate.